# Monitor jboss with jconsole

Tags: jboss, jconsole

I want monitor my jboss with jconsole . As I know had to just add follow to java_opts is that correct? How should add this?
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616”

Answer (score 0):

No it is not correct, you need to have a proper classpath set. Use the jconsole script provided.

Comment: Would you please help me about it ? How should I do it ?